# pattern matching in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

In the program I am trying to look for pattern in content. If any of the pattern H Q 9 is found in string taken by user it should print `YES` else `NO`. So I used three bool `flag1` `flag2` `flag3`. My code gives wrong output if input is `codeforces`. Desired output is `NO` instead of `YES`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean flag1 = false; 
    boolean flag2 = false; 
    boolean flag3 = false;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();
    String text = s;
    String pat1 = ".*H*.";
    String pat2 = ".*Q*.";
    String pat3 = ".*9*.";
    //boolean isMatch = Pattern.matches(pattern, content);
    flag1 = Pattern.matches(pat1, text);
    flag2 = Pattern.matches(pat2, text);
    flag3 = Pattern.matches(pat3,text);

    if (flag1 == true || flag2 == true || flag3 == true)
        System.out.println("YES");
    else
        System.out.println("NO");
}
```

Comment: You still don't have a question there, but I'm assuming your issue is that the word "codeforces" is outputting "YES" and you want it to output "NO". The first thing I'd advise you do is change that regex so pat1 is [HQ9] and get rid of pat2 and pat3 entirely. You can match any of the three characters with one pattern so there's no need to have a bunch of separate ones and then use flags to determine whether any of them were present.

Answer (score 4):

Your regexps are wrong - `H*` means "any number of Hs, including zero", and likewise for both other regexps.

Thus, `.*H*.` means that your text should contain an arbitrary number of "something", then an arbitrary number of Hs (or none, as "zero Hs" is also allowed), and then an arbitrary letter.

`codeforces` fulfils these criteria, as it contains of an arbitrary number of letters, no H and ends with an arbitrary letter.

Your regexps will match any input which has at least once character.

Comment: Great answer Gunter, especially with the edit, but it would be better IMO if you explained to satya how to fix it rather than just saying what's wrong. Have an upvote anyway.

Comment: Ok, will do so in the future - now others already overtook on both sides in this regard... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using three regular expressions is redundant. I recommend just using one.

I also refactored and reformatted your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();

    boolean matches = Pattern.matches(".*[HQ9].*", s);

    if (matches)
    {
        System.out.println("YES");
    } else
    {
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
}
```

You could compress the method even further:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();

    boolean matches = Pattern.matches("[HQ9]", s);
    System.out.println(matches ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```

The regular expression `.*[HQ9].*` does the following: It searches for any characters equal to the ones found inside of the square brackets:

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer so far and gets a well-deserved +1 from me.

Comment: I copy-pasted the above code, and entered "code 9 page", and it returns NO.  You need the `.*` before and after the `[HQ9]`.

Comment: Ok.  See my answer (that someone has downvoted).  It contains code that can be pasted, compiled and run.

Answer (score 1):

Although someone has already explained the problem (I do not want to take credit from others), here are a few suggestions to reduce and more importantly **test** your code

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Test75B {
  public static final String[] TESTS = {
    "codeforces", 
    "Back to Headquarters", 
    "A cat has nine lives", 
    "A cat has 9 lives", 
    "Is it a Query or a Quarry?", 
    "How Can You Quote 4+5=9!"
  };
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String text: TESTS) {
      boolean flag1=false; 
      String pat1= ".*[HQ9].*";
      System.out.println(text);
      flag1=Pattern.matches(pat1, text);
      System.out.println( flag1 ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output I get

```
codeforces
NO
Back to Headquarters
YES
A cat has nine lives
NO
A cat has 9 lives
YES
Is it a Query or a Quarry?
YES
How Can You Quote 4+5=9!
YES
```

As an easy test, remove the `.*` in the regex, recompile and look at the output.  You will see they are required.

Comment: If you want to avoid the `.*`, you can obtain a Matcher and use its [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())-method.